# How can we detect when the model is back to its original value?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

**[JS Bin here](http://jsbin.com/suxubi/edit?output)**

[This article](http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/post.cfm/determining-if-data-has-changed-in-your-angularjs-powered-form) describes a clever way to see if your (pure Angular) form model has changed since the initial load. In my mind it's a more accurate test of `$dirty`/`$pristine`. This allows us to do things like hide the "Save" button for a form if the model hasn't changed, even if the user has typed then deleted text.

So the question is, how can we do this with angular-formly? My hunch is that `onChange` for each field might be a good starting point, but I'm having a lot of trouble putting together the rest of the solution.

Hope the question makes sense. Any ideas would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: i think you can do it same way, you just need to watch the model and compare it.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I thought I had tried this without luck, but with a lead on Gitter I got a working solution [here](http://jsbin.com/domoko/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

This might work in a limited capacity:

```
scope.initialValue;
var listener = scope.$watch(function(oldVal,newVal){
       scope.initialValue = oldVal
       listener();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[atinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1125167/atinder) was correct in that the pure Angular approach actually works fine with angular-formly. I've created a working JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/domoko/edit?html,js,output).